# Python Loop Board Game

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm writing a function called `init_carre(tab)` that needs to place 9 "X" in the center of a board. This is the code I have written so far:

```
from copy import deepcopy 
n = int(input("Nombre de colonnes et lignes? "))

def initialisation():
    board = [["." for i in range(n)]for j in range(n)] 
    return board

def affichage(tab):
    t = 0       
    while t<n:             
        for a in tab:
            print("".join(a)) 
            t += 1 
            
def init_carre(tab):
    tableau2 = deepcopy(tab) 
    bacterie = "X" 
    ligne = round(n/2) 
    colonne = round(n/2) 
    tableau2[ligne-1][colonne] = bacterie    #Need to loop this part  !!!!!!!
    tableau2[ligne-1][colonne-1] = bacterie 
    tableau2[ligne-1][colonne-2] = bacterie
    tableau2[ligne-2][colonne] = bacterie
    tableau2[ligne-2][colonne-1] = bacterie
    tableau2[ligne-2][colonne-2] = bacterie
    tableau2[ligne][colonne] = bacterie
    tableau2[ligne][colonne-1] = bacterie
    tableau2[ligne][colonne-2] = bacterie        
    return tableau2 
   
            
affichage(initialisation())
print("")
affichage(init_carre(initialisation()))
```

I need help to loop the lines that start in the comment "Need to loop this part" and I appreciate if you have any advice on how to improve the code

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by 2 nested loops like this:

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        tableau2[ligne-i][colonne-j] = bacterie
```

Comment: And if you want `ligne` and `colonne` to specify the center of the square of X's, you could change `range(3)` to `[-1, 0, 1]` or `range(-1, 2)`. It's also a good idea to check that `(ligne-i, colonne-j)` aren't outside the `tableau2` and aren't negative.

Comment: If the answer helped you please consider accepting it